# jQuery.Lazy Vimeo Issues

Tags: lazy-loading, vimeo

I'm using jQuery.Lazy to make images load a little smoother on my website. It works like a charm on images, but I'm having some trouble with embedded Vimeo videos.

I have the full packaged jquery.lazy.min.js uploaded and I call it using the following scripts:

```
$('.lazy').lazy({
        effect: "fadeIn",
        effectTime: 300,
        threshold: 0
    });

$("iframe").lazy({
    effect: "fadeIn",
    effectTime: 300,
    threshold: 0
});
```

All images with a class of .lazy and the data-src tag load perfectly. But when I try to embed Vimeo using the example from their GitHub [document notes](https://github.com/eisbehr-/jquery.lazy/tree/master/plugins#vimeo-video-loader) nothing happens.

Here's the code they show as an example:
`<iframe data-loader="vimeo" data-src="176894130" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>`

And this is what I'm embeding on my site:
`<iframe class="lazy" data-loader="vimeo" data-src="254984504" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>`